# What happens when I go to an URL directly?

Tags: ember.js

I'm confused by Ember's behaviour.  I have this piece of code (in CoffeeScript):

```
Terminal.Router.map () ->
  @resource('path', {path: '/path/:path'})

Terminal.PathRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, path) ->
    console.log "Breakpoint A"
  renderTemplate: () ->
    console.log "Breakpoint B"
```

When I navigate from my index page to this route, both print statements are executed.  And yet when I directly go to a route like `/#/path/abc`, these statements are not executed.  In fact, no template is rendered.

Can someone explain this behaviour?  What do I need to do to make it so that a user will see the same content whether he visits this route directly or transitions from another route?

Comment: which version of ember.js are your using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [ember.js rc6](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js) which introduced some fundamental changes aka [*(router facelift)*](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) this behaviour is being syncronized to be the same. Have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) for more info.

**Note taken from the docs**

> Previous iterations of the router exposed a hook called redirect, which gave you the opportunity to transitionTo another route, thus aborting the present transition attempt. **The problem with this is that when async data was involved, the behavior between transitionTo/linkTo behavior and URL navigation behavior was very different and not easily predictable.**

But now they are in sync and should yield the same behaviuor.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but as far as I know if you go to this link `/#/path/abc` you need to be sure that `resource` with `id` `abc` exists.

Answer (score 0):

> When I navigate from my index page to this route, both print statements are executed. And yet when I directly go to a route like /#/path/abc, these statements are not executed. In fact, no template is rendered. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Not possible to explain without more info. Try adding the following to your app so that you can watch console and see what is going on. Watch the output when you visit route directly - is router transitioning into the route you expect? How does that output compare to what happens when you follow a link from the index page?

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
});
```

See http://blog.emberwatch.com/2013/06/13/logging-the-magic-in-ember-js.html for explanation of these settings.

> What do I need to do to make it so that a user will see the same content whether he visits this route directly or transitions from another route?

Like @intuitivepixel said, there used to be some differences but with the latest version of router this should be the default behavior. In other words, you should not need to do anything at all.